# Two bugs in 'How to Ask' in Channels

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, stack-overflow-for-teams

Two bugs in the 'How to Ask' section in Channels:

[image]

> **Is your question about on-topic**

seems to be missing a word (or can we define that somewhere in the Channel's settings?)

and the 'ask it on meta' link links to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), though I expect it to link to Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't know if redirecting those questions to MSO is the right call. I, for one, don't have access to Channels, and discussions about it are likely irrelevant to me. MSE is quite a bit broader than MSO, and more about discussing the network in general. Channels will have a different community than the general SO community. I could imagine that questions about channels fit in better there. There might even be a case for a channels-specific meta.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth true, but up to now all communication about Channels took place *here*. The URL even starts with stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Also, Channels/Teams are SO specific.

Comment: The entire "ask on Meta instead" guidance is apparently erroneous, at least at this point in time. The guidance we have received in Charcoal is to post there, in our own Teams (aka Channels) instance, but apply the [tag:meta] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This content has been dramatically simplified.

Comment: The content of this answer has been dramatically simplified as well.